# PHP script execution stops during big SQL execution

Tags: php, mysql

Am executing PHP script to migrate tables from one server DB to another server DB.

The script unnecessarily stops execution during large no. of INSERT command is executed.
eg:transfer 15000rows to a table using `mysqli_query("INSERT INTo....VALUES(....)")` then execution stops.

already initialized:
`set_time_limit(0);`
`ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', '0');`
`ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');`

Is there any other solutions available?

Comment: is there any error output ?

Comment: no nothing displayed on screen

Comment: Is it possible to split your query into multiple queries, where the queries would insert smaller amount of rows?

Comment: @PetrNovak , it's a good comment, but unfortunately i already tried this.    Actually the exact problem arrives when the large no. of rows table operates. One more thing is that the particular table is successfully completed insertion, the error occurs with the next table's.

Comment: Can you then split one script into multiple scripts (let's say one script per table), so the script won't timeout?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since you asked the question, but I am having a similar problem and I just solved it by using:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

As long as you are not running your script in safe mode, though. Otherwise, you will have to change the time limit in php.ini.

Hope this helps to someone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Please Declare

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '-1');
```

Comment: is it really a solution?

Comment: Yes.. you will try this